# Is it necessary to convert a bytearray of PNG data to base64 before rendering it on a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file that contains multiple PNG images (along with other types of data). Think of it like a zip file or some other archive format.

Upon receiving a response from the server, I will receive a bytearray containing all of the data I need.

I then proceed to parse it, extracting the PNG data in the process.

After the parsing is finished, I have a collection of bytearrays that hold PNG data, and now I would like to draw them to the webpage.

Many examples I've looked at say that each byte array must be converted into base64, and then use that as the `src` for an image, which can then be used to draw on the canvas.

1. Is this the standard way to display images manually?
2. Is this what does the browser does when it renders an `img` tag and sees a `src` attribute that references a URI?

Comment: An alternative to converting it to base64, is create a blob from the byte array and use [createObjectUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I haven't heard of object URL's before. I will take a closer look at it.